# Rotation of cylinder within another object

Tags: modeling

[image: cylinder rotation within object]
This cylinder is subdivided by 32 which is the default. But I need it to rotate smoothly and firmly inside its surrounding object. I'm tempted to subdivide to 1024 but then there's the argument "How high is enough?" I know there's a tool that makes the surface of the cylinder and outer object glassy smooth. But relying on a smoothing tool algorithm could destroy the tight fit and allow a small gap between the objects.

Does anyone have any advice here before I start 3D printing?

Comment: Is there any reason why there can't be a tiny gap between them? After all, it's not as if they are physical objects where an interference fit is needed.

Comment: All I can say about the specs is that parts must be robust with firmness of fit and smooth rotation. If I have more information before the 3D printing there will be a lot less experimentation and lost time.

Comment: There was no mention of 3D printing in the question! Were we supposed to guess?

Comment: Just fixed the question to include that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done lots of 3D printing from blender. smoothing does nothing for your prints (its only a visual trick). If you double your vertices should be more than enough. Depending on your 3D printer and print resolution. For a tight fit you need to make some tests anyways, all printers and materials have different shrink properties. i would take 0.25mm gap between the parts to start with if you are printing in plastic.

Comment: (3D-printing-know-nothing here) .. is there  any harm in taking the resolution as high as you like? What are the downsides?

Comment: That's a key point Robin. All I know is that the higher you go, the slower the software responds as you do more work.

Comment: Roel, I'll start with your suggested gap of 0.25 mm and experiment from there. Thank you...

Comment: With resin printers or SLS powder printers you can go highter in resolution. the higher the better but it is usually not neccesary. Ony if you make really big print like on a 1m2 3D printer (like a bigrep) you want to max out your subdivisions.